# Leading Riesz potential to use Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality.

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $\gamma>0$ and $f,g$ are complex valued integrable functions on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (like Schwartz space).

I want to show that, the $L^{1}$ norm of Fourier transform (or inversion) of convolution of inverse power type and inner product $f\bar{g}$ leads to use Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality, i.e.

$$
\| \mathcal{F}^{\pm 1}(|\cdot|^{-\gamma}\ast(f\bar{g}))\|_{L^1} \le C \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{|\hat{f}(\xi)||\hat{\bar{g}}(\eta)|}{|\xi-\eta|^{n-\gamma}}d\xi d\eta,
$$
where $\mathcal{F}^{\pm}$ are Fourier transform and its inversion, respectively.
In my work, I tried to use change of variables to the following procedure:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\big| |\xi|^{-(n-\gamma)}\widehat{fg}(\xi)\big|d\xi
\le C \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\xi|^{-(n-\gamma)}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}|\hat{f}(\xi-\eta)||\hat{\bar{g}}(\eta)|d\eta d\xi.
$$

But, I cannot lead to anythings. I think it is simple, but cannot find its simpleness.

Comment: Sorry, I may find it. Convolution $(|\cdot|^{-(n-\gamma)}\ast \hat{f})(\eta)$ yields desired inequality.

Comment: Just do the change of variable $\xi \leftrightarrow \eta - \xi$.

Comment: The change of variables yields that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2n}} \frac{|\hat{f}(-\xi)||\hat{\bar{g}}(\eta)}{|\xi-\eta|^{n-\gamma}}(-1)^{n} d\eta d\xi$. Oh, I see. Each ranges of integral for $\xi_i$ leads what I want. Thanks.